# Sortable combo box with columns

Tags: wpf, combobox, sorting

I have a combo with more than one value in it (different bindings from the same source)
I would like to create a combo box where the user could sort by those columns and also include a header to clarify the informations

Example :

Item No | Name | Rank
00      | foo  | 0
01      | bar  | 2
02      | too  | 1

We could sort by Item No, Name or rank.

Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it with a `ComboBox` is definitely possible, but involves changing the entire `ComboBox` template such that the `Popup` hosts a `ListView`. As a simpler alternative, you might consider just using a `ToggleButton` and `Popup`, with a `ListView` inside the `Popup`.

Comment: I thought it was too complex to be able to do it easily, but your solution sounds nice.